# Kubernetes egress rule blocks all outgoing traffic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

**The Problem**

I've defined a kubernetes `egress` rule from pod `test-1` to a specific pod `test-2`, but this rule blocks also blocks traffic from `test-1` to `test-2`:

1. I've created two pods: `test-1` and `test-2`
2. I've created a networkpolicy that allows only `egress` traffic from `test-1` to `test-2`
3. I've tried to call `test-2` from `test-1` by `curl test-2`. But this call is blocked!
4. I've checked the selectors

Both selectors return the expected pod:

```
kubectl describe networkpolicies test-1-policy
kubectl get pod --selector app.kubernetes.io/name=test-1
kubectl get pod --selector app.kubernetes.io/name=test-2
```

When I remove the `networkpolicy` the connect by `curl test-2` works.

**My Question: What did I miss?**

**Here's how to reproduce the problem**

1. Paste yaml into file `deployment.yaml` (see below)
2. Deploy demo `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`
3. Exec into pod: `kubectl exec --stdin --tty $(kubectl get pod -l app.kubernetes.io/name=test-1 -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") -- /bin/bash`
4. Call request in pod: `curl test-2` => **request is blocked**
5. Remove networkpolicy: `kubectl delete networkpolicy test-1-policy`
6. Exec in pod and call request => **request is executed**

Here's the complete yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: test-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: test-2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-2
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-2
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-1-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test-1
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
  ingress: []
  egress:
    - to:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/name: test-2
      ports:
        - port: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dns `egress` rule is missing:

When you add the `egress` rules for `port 53` everything works as expected:

```
  egress:
    - ports:
      - port: 53
        protocol: UDP
      - port: 53
        protocol: TCP
```

https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/11-deny-egress-traffic-from-an-application.md